# Node.js does not recognize model definitions across multiple files

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My app.js `require`s these files:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Custom Modules
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/models').forEach(function(filename) {
    if (filename.indexOf('.js')) require(__dirname + '/models/' + filename)
});

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
```

So, as you can see, mongoose first, the model files within /models/ second and the route files within /routes/ last. Within one of the model files, `posts.js`, i define this:

```
var Post = mongoose.model('posts', postsSchema);
```

Because of the require order, i would think that `Post` would be accessible from everywhere *below* the /models/ require. However, accessing `Post` like the following from within `/routes/index.js` throws an error, saying `Post` is undefined:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.get('/submit/', function (req, res) {
    var submission = new Post({
        // ...
    });
});
```

I can access `Post` from within `/models/posts.js`, but not from anywhere else. What is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To use the variable Post you need to assign the variable first. Like this:
`var Post = require('path/to/your/models/post')`

To bake this into your forEach, though, you will need some more work. Consider if your automation is really necessary. You may find that doing it manually makes it more readable.

Comment: The way to do it is `require('mongoose')` in your other files, then get access to `Post` by `var Post = mongoose.model('Post')`

Comment: Thank you! I figured out that i also have to append `module.exports = Post;` at the end of /modules/posts.js so that the model gets passed along. I wonder, why do i even have to require these .js files in app.js if i have to require them individually within my routes files anyway? Is this the correct practice?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to export it like that, as long as you create a model out of the schema with mongoose, anything that requires the same copy of mongoose will have access to those models using the `model('modelName')` method.

Comment: take a look at this [boilerplate project](http://meanjs.org/) you can get a feel of one way of doing it

Comment: Alright, thank you both, i figured it out now. My model files just register the models in one line `mongoose.model('posts', postsSchema);`, and this can be defined as a variable from anywhere (where `require('mongoose')` happened) as `var Post = mongoose.model('posts');`. Way easier than i thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each module lives in it's own namespace so a regular top-level variable definition such as:

```
var Post = mongoose.model('posts', postsSchema);
```

is not a globally accessible variable.  That variable is only accessible within that module.

To expand the scope of where that variable can be used, you have several options:

1. You can export the variable so that the module that `require()` you in can access the model direct from the exports.
2. You can export a method that allows anyone who `require()` your model can then call to fetch that variable.  I refer to this as the "pull" model of export where other modules "pull" a value from you.
3. You can call methods in other modules and send the variable to them.  I refer to this as the "push" model of export because you're sending a value to another module.
4. You can explicitly declare a global using the nodejs `global` symbol.  `global.Post = mongoose.model('posts', postsSchema);`.  And, then other places in the code can reference it the same way.